# recursion on bst in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a Binary Search Tree class, and getting confused as to how the while loop works.

```
if (value === currentNode.value) return;
```

if the same value entered is already in there return false, but this is also the base case?

if I take it out, the code breaks. how does it break the loop when I'm not entered an existing value?

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
}

class BinarySearchTree {
  constructor() {
    this.root = null;
  }

  insert(value) {
    const newNode = new Node(value);
    if (this.root === null) this.root = newNode;  
    let currentNode = this.root;


    while (currentNode !== null) {
      if (value === currentNode.value) return;

      if (value < currentNode.value) {
        if (currentNode.left === null) currentNode.left = newNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.left;
      } else {
        if (currentNode.right === null) currentNode.right = newNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.right;
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Your logic looks a bit off to me.  I would expect to see you returning in the base immediately, rather than allowing it to flow to the broader if-else statement.

Comment: `while (currentNode !== null)` is pointless as `currentNode` can never be `null` in your code. This loop is basically a `while(true)`. You could put your abort condition in there: `while(value !== currentNode.value)`

Answer (score 0):

Your loop break because you if condition only check for values less than or greater than and equal. You need a to insert `if (value === currentNode.value) return;`
 inside else condition. Basically, inside else you need to check if the value is equal or greater than. Right now you don't check it.

```
insert(value) {
  const newNode = new Node(value);
  if (this.root === null) this.root = newNode;  
  let currentNode = this.root;


  while (currentNode !== null) {
    if (value < currentNode.value) {
      if (currentNode.left === null) currentNode.left = newNode;
      currentNode = currentNode.left;
    } else {
      if (value === currentNode.value) return false;
      if (currentNode.right === null) currentNode.right = newNode;
      currentNode = currentNode.right;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another insert methods you can try

```
class Node {
constructor(value) {
this.value = value;
this.left = null;
this.right = null;
  }
}

class BinarySearchTree {
  constructor() {
  this.root = null;
  }

  insert(value){
  let newNode = new Node(value);

   if(this.rootNode == null){
    this.rootNode = newNode;
    return this;
   }else{
    let currentNode = this.rootNode;
     while(true){
      if(value > currentNode.value){
       if(currentNode.right == null){
        currentNode.right = newNode;
        return this;
       }
      currentNode = currentNode.right;
     }else if(value < currentNode.value){
      if(currentNode.left == null){
       currentNode.left = newNode;
       return this;
     }
    currentNode = currentNode.left;
  }
 }
 }
}
```